# build method of subclass that extends RouterDelegate is not rebuild when App's state changed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, router

When app is open,the first_screen widget must display until 3seconds and after the time passed home_page widget must show that I expect.But,after over 3seconds,home_page is not appear.State changing is notified from provider to Router.Which part is error?Please!!
My router `app_route.dart` is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigator_2/keys/screen_keys.dart';
import 'package:navigator_2/provider/tab_provider.dart';
import 'package:navigator_2/root_screen.dart';
import 'package:navigator_2/screens/first_screen.dart';

class AppRoute extends RouterDelegate<AppKey> with ChangeNotifier,PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin{

  @override
  late final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKeys;

  final TabManager _tabManager;

  AppRoute(this._tabManager) : navigatorKeys = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(){
    _tabManager.addListener(() {notifyListeners();});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("${_tabManager.isInitialPage}");
    print("${_tabManager.currentTab}");
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKeys,
      onPopPage: _handlePopPage,
      pages: [
        if(!_tabManager.isInitialPage) FirstScreen.page(),
        if(_tabManager.isInitialPage == true)...{
          RootScreen.page(_tabManager.currentTab)
        },
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(configuration) {
    // TODO: implement setNewRoutePath
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
  

  bool _handlePopPage(Route<dynamic> route, result) {
    if(!route.didPop(result)){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement navigatorKey
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? get navigatorKey => navigatorKeys;

}`
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.dart is

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigator_2/provider/tab_provider.dart';
import 'package:navigator_2/router_api/app_route.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late AppRoute _appRoute;
  TabManager tabManager = TabManager();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _appRoute = AppRoute(tabManager);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TabManager())
          ],
          child: Router(routerDelegate: _appRoute),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```